# Linqpad working directory

Tags: .net, linqpad

What is the working directory for my code when I run it in Linqpad? 
Is there a UI to specify it?

Comment: Just like any other program on Windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer right now, is that LINQPad's working directory is undefined.

Yes, there's a good argument for making this predictable and for there to be Util.Cd method to change it. Let's dicsuss it here to avoid the StackOverflow off-topic police: http://forum.linqpad.net/